# Show that if $x^2 - 3x + 2 < 0$, then $1 < x < 2$ by contraposition.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm back for more. I am aware that this is more easily done by the direct method, however the assignment requires that it be done by contraposition. I have created the following proof:

*Proof:* (contraposition)
 Suppose: $x \geq 2$ or $x \leq 1$.
   case 1: $x \leq 1.$
    Note that $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x - 1)(x - 2).$
    If $x \leq 1$, then both terms are nonpositive.
    Thus, $x^2 - 3x + 2 \geq 0.$

case 2: $x \geq 2.$
    Again, note that $x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x - 1)(x - 2).$
    If $x \geq 2$, then both terms are nonnegative.
    Thus, $x^2 - 3x + 2 \geq 0.$
$\Box$

Please help by pointing out the flaws, even if the whole thing is flawed.

Comment: It's easier to point out that when $x\le 1$ or $x\ge 2$ then both factors $x-1$ and $x-2$ have the same sign and therefore, their product must be non-negative.

Comment: Both parts are  wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Case 1, when you write $$(x - 1)(x - 2) \ge (0)(x - 2),$$
you are using the fact $x \leq 2$ in this case and thus, the inequality is reversed. Analogous comment for Case 2 also holds. You should mention this.

Also, you have a "$\exists x \in \Bbb Z$" there thrown randomly in the middle which I don't understand. It shouldn't be there.

---

Here is how I would have written it:

Note that $$x^2 - 3x + 2 = (x - 1)(x - 2).$$
Thus, if $x \leqslant 1$, then both terms above are nonpositive and thus, the expression is $\geqslant 0$.
Similarly, if $x \geqslant 2$, then both terms above are...

Comment: My professor is a strict on quantifiers, which is why I added it.

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta: That does not mean that you can just add it anywhere. There is no need for any quantifier there. Moreover, why are you assuming that $x$ is an integer?

Comment: Ohhh... I think I see what you mean now. The quantifier doesn't make sense because I've already defined it.

Comment: Is it ok to "pick" a number in the cases?

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta: Not sure what you mean by "pick". Choosing $x$ concretely to be something $0$ or $4.5$ does give anything, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I meant choosing an $x$. Did you mean to say that choosing an appropriate value for $x$ does NOT give anything? I am still uncomfortable using words in a proof. I'm sorry for my difficulties, but I am trying to learn.

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta: You are correct. I, unfortunately, ate up the "NOT".

Comment: I have edited my post. Is that better?

Comment: @IndiaJ.Delta: In Case 2, I would write "nonnegative" instead of "positive". Else it is OK.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong. For case 1,
$$ x\le  1\Rightarrow x-1\le 0, x-2\le-1<0\Rightarrow(x-1)(x-2)\ge0.$$
The same thing for case 2.